# Akavache throwing System.MissingMethodException: Only when Xamarin.Forms Android app is built on VS2022

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, reactiveui, visual-studio-2022, akavache

I have an app made with Xamarin Forms, that uses Akavache to cache data.
The app works well on iOS and Android in debug mode when I make a build with VS2019
But when I installed VS2022 and decided to make a build for android, an error occurred.
This error only occurs after I build and deploy the app with VS 2022. Nothing else was changed in the project.

Here is the error:

> [AppCenterCrashes] Unhandled Exception from source=AndroidEnvironment
> [AppCenterCrashes] System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.ReadOnlySpan`1<byte> SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_column_blob(SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt,int) [AppCenterCrashes]   at Akavache.Sqlite3.SqliteOperationQueue.MarshalCompletion[T] (System.Object completion, System.Func`1[TResult] block, System.IObservable`1[T] commitResult) [0x00012] in D:\a\Akavache\Akavache\src\Akavache.Sqlite3\Queues\OperationQueue.cs:488
> [AppCenterCrashes] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: Does this happen with other apps?

Comment: Yes, it happens for every app I built that uses Akavache.

Comment: If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: This occurs for me in the .GetCreatedAt method